# Effect of random matrices on the product of two perpendicular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrix

For two non-square perpendicular matrices $X$ and $Y$ (i.e., $X^T Y = 0$), what happens when we bring a random matrix $A \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ (with i.i.d. elements) to the inner product, as follows?

$X^T (A^T A) Y = \text{?}$

I'm interested in how the norm of this multiplication behaves. e.g., can we say it's zero? Or can we provide an upperbound for $||X^T (A^T A) Y||_2$ ?

Comment: First solve the problem for *vectors* $X$ and $Y,$ assuming both are nonzero.  I believe you can easily derive the distribution.  If that's unclear, first consider the case $X=(1,0,\ldots,0)^\prime$ and $Y=(0,1,0,\ldots,0)^\prime$ and write out the expression in terms of components of $A.$

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've been playing around with it for a while but no luck so far... Do you think the fact that X and Y are perpendicular is relevant here? Could it be of any use at all? Another thing is that I'm not interested in the distribution, I'm more interested in how the l2 norm of that matrix multiplication behaves.